Applying specific styling to group layers in the LayerList Widget in ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript
Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.24, I would like to change the formatting of Group Layers within the LayerList Widget, such that the group layers can be immediately distinguished from non-group layers when the user views the LayerList widget.
Here is a mockup which I created by manually adjusting the styling of the Group layers using the browser debug toolbar:

This screenshot was taken from the Esri LayerList sample code which uses a default LayerList widget:
const layerList = new LayerList({
  view: view
});
view.ui.add(layerList, "top-right");

See the sample at https://jsfiddle.net/slead/ymLc6o3j/6/
Note that 2 of the layers are Group Layers. How can I target the Group layers using CSS selectors, or otherwise achieve this programmatically?
As far as I can see, all layers have the class .esri-layer-list__item-title and Group layers don't have a different class.

@TomazicM fair enough. I updated the question to use the default Esri LayerList sample code.

Additional full JS Fiddle does no harm, it can be helpful, so I returned it to the question.

There seems to be no built-in method to do this. One possible solution is to set mutation observer on layer list HTML container, watch for changes of attribute open (it changes for list item when it is expanded/collapsed) and set style of the first child item, which is the text of the list item.
The code could then look something like this (tested):
const layerList = new LayerList({
  view: view
});
view.ui.add(layerList, "top-right");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(records){
  records.find(function(record) {
    if (record.attributeName == 'open') {
      var expandedStyle = (record.target.open) ? 'color: red;' : '';
      record.target.children[0].style = expandedStyle;
      return(true);
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(layerList.container, {attributes: true, subtree: true});       

Here is the working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/mepv4Lda/
Edit of the question which now says "such that the group layers can be immediately distinguished from non-group layers when the user views the LayerList widget" means that group header items must have constantly different styles.
To identify list items in layerList container that are group headers:

find all lists with query selector 'calcite-list';
iterate through the list, skipping elements with the group='root' attribute;
for each list element find its group header item by id, where id is taken from the group attribute;
change the style of the group header first child to the desired style.

The code could then look something like this (tested):
const layerList = new LayerList({
    view: view
});

view.ui.add(layerList, {
    position: "top-right"
});

var listItemFound = false;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(records){
  records.find(function(record) {
    if (record.target.className == 'esri-layer-list__item') {
      listItemFound = true;
    }
  });
  if (listItemFound) {
    var lists = layerList.container.querySelectorAll('calcite-list');
    lists.forEach(function(list) {
      if (list.group != 'root') {
        var item = document.getElementById(list.group);
        item.children[0].style = 'color: red;';
      }
    });
    observer.disconnect();
  }
});
observer.observe(layerList.container, {attributes: true, subtree: true}); 


This is a great workaround, thanks. Unfortunately I need the formatting to apply even before the user has opened the group layer, in order to comply with a supplied design

You didn't specify that in your question. On image both groups are opened.

noted - I've updated the question to specify this

Have a look at edited answer.

Genius - many thanks
